# Selenium: Upon initiating ChromeDriver, an additional tab opens

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Every time I launch my ChromeDriver a second tab is instantly opened to this link, "http://www.ietab.net/thanks-installing-ie-tab".

How do I prevent the ChromeDriver from opening this tab?

Thank you,
~Sid

Comment: Maybe you should disable IE tab extension if you have one?

Comment: I got this fix. Thanks for the answers, and sorry it took me so long to get back. I don't know how to get StackOverflow to inform me when someone responds to one of my posts.